# Performance issue to calculate node_centrality and edge_centrality on large Data

Tags: python, openstreetmap, networkx, osmnx

My Local Osm File contains filtered data (Filtered through OSMFilter) of Germany and that contains only following highways

1. motorway
2. motorway_link
3. trunk
4. trunk_link
5. primary
6. primary_link
7. secondary
8. secondary_link
9. tertiary
10. tertiary_link
11. residential
12. living_street

I am trying to simplify graph and extracting important information to minimize my road network more. I have followed following steps

1. G3 = ox.simplify_graph(G, strict=True)
2. G3 = ox.add_edge_lengths(G3);
3. G3 = ox.remove_isolated_nodes(G3);
4. node_centrality = nx.closeness_centrality(G3)
5. nx.set_node_attributes(G3, node_centrality, 'node_centrality')
6. edge_centrality = nx.closeness_centrality(nx.line_graph(G3))
7. nx.set_edge_attributes(G3, edge_centrality, 'edge_centrality')
8. ox.save_load.save_graphml(G3,..,..,..)

It have waited around a all day to see output in GraphML but did not see any progress . . 
I think edge_centrality and edge_centrality are hight computational functions but how I can use these functions for my data ?

Answer (score 0):

Which specific step is accounting for the long runtime? As networkx calculates these measures, they will inevitably be slow with a massive network (such as that of all of Germany), given the nature of the algorithms' time complexity. If networkx is a bottleneck, considering converting to [graph-tool](https://gist.github.com/bbengfort/a430d460966d64edc6cad71c502d7005) and running the algorithms there.

Comment: these steps:node_centrality = nx.closeness_centrality(G3)
nx.set_node_attributes(G3, node_centrality, 'node_centrality')
edge_centrality = nx.closeness_centrality(nx.line_graph(G3))
nx.set_edge_attributes(G3, edge_centrality, 'edge_centrality')

Comment: All of them? So the `node_centrality = nx.closeness_centrality(G3)` step completed and you have confirmed that the subsequent `nx.set_node_attributes(G3, node_centrality, 'node_centrality')` step also has a long runtime? How long is this latter step's runtime?

Comment: yes all of these functions . . it worked on one State of Germany but for all coutry OSM i do not get response...i have waited for more than 12 hours and still i did not get any output . . i ended up in frustration and i had to close .. . i tried it again but still same response . .